# Релизная версия моего приложения не запускается на Meizu. А на остальных запускается

Tags: android, delphi, google-play, radstudio, firemonkey

Дебажный апк работает везде. А релизный апк (не важно, устанавливался с googleplay, или руками, через запуск самого апк) не работает на Meizu m2. Чтобы вы понимали, телефон нормальный, с нормальной прошивкой, на нем работает все, кроме моего приложения. На других телефонах полет нормальный. Тестировал на galaxy, xperia, zenfone.

"Не работает" значит, что при нажатии на иконку приложения видно секундное затухание экрана, как будто сейчас что-то включится и... все. Снова рабочий стол.

Делалось оно в RAD Studio, на Delphi (прошу, не говорите ничего об этом, делал не я, сейчас приходится заставлять этого монстра работать, сам в шоке) с использованием FireMonkey. И да, оно кроссплатформенное. Тот же код я компилирую под iOS и оно работает.

Я даже не знаю, честно говоря, что тут еще добавить. В чем, вообще, может быть проблема? Для меня это похоже на какую-то магию.

Вот логи из events_log

```
09-30 02:01:44.749   787  1546 I am_create_activity: [0,215441632,364,com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity,android.intent.action.MAIN,NULL,NULL,270532608]
09-30 02:01:44.749   787  1546 I wm_task_created: [364,1]
09-30 02:01:44.749   787  1546 I wm_task_moved: [364,1,9]
09-30 02:01:44.801   787  1546 I am_pause_activity: [0,750531609,com.meizu.flyme.launcher/.Launcher]
09-30 02:01:44.818   787  1546 I am_home_stack_moved: [0,0,1,1,startedActivity setFocusedActivity]
09-30 02:01:44.819   787  1546 I am_focused_activity: [0,com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity]
09-30 02:01:44.836  1512  1512 I am_on_paused_called: [0,com.meizu.flyme.launcher.Launcher]
09-30 02:01:44.871   787  1320 I am_proc_start: [0,1563,10088,com.il.GS,activity,com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity]
09-30 02:01:44.936   787   849 I am_proc_bound: [0,1563,com.il.GS]
09-30 02:01:44.940   787   849 I am_restart_activity: [0,215441632,364,com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity]
09-30 02:01:44.947   787   849 I am_focused_activity: [0,com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity]
09-30 02:01:45.077   787  1490 I am_crash: [1563,0,com.il.GS,8961604,java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,Unable to find native library: GS,NativeActivity.java,170]
09-30 02:01:45.079   787  1490 I am_finish_activity: [0,215441632,364,com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity,crashed]
09-30 02:01:45.079   787  1490 I am_home_stack_moved: [0,1,0,0,finishActivity adjustFocus]
09-30 02:01:45.079   787  1490 I wm_task_moved: [16,1,0]
09-30 02:01:45.096   787  1490 I am_home_stack_moved: [0,1,0,0,finishActivity adjustTopFocus setFocusedActivity]
09-30 02:01:45.098   787  1490 I am_focused_activity: [0,com.meizu.flyme.launcher/.Launcher]
09-30 02:01:45.112   787  1490 I am_pause_activity: [0,215441632,com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity]
09-30 02:01:45.183   787  1469 I am_proc_died: [0,1563,com.il.GS]
```

Логично предположить что проблема вот здесь: `IllegalArgumentException,Unable to find native library: GS,NativeActivity.java,170`
Сейчас постараюсь нагуглить что-то по этому вопросу

В main_log нашел вот такое:

```
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.il.GS, PID: 1563
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: GS
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:180)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5824)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1010)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: GS
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:170)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity.onCreate(FMXNativeActivity.java:139)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6107)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
09-30 02:01:45.076  1563  1563 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 10 more
```

Господа, все еще не разобрался, как это можно исправить. Логи говорят что java не находит нативную библиотеку, с названием моего приложения. Что это вообще значит? Почему на дебаг-версии находит? Или не ищет? Почему только релизник вылетает? Что вообще значат эти записи в логах, и что за таинственная native libriary под названием GS (так, предположим, называется и приложение). Откуда ей вообще взяться?

Comment: А в логах то есть что-то?

Comment: Только пытаюсь сейчас как-то до них добраться, насколько я понял оно  их либо не пишет вообще, либо нужно рутнуть телефон чтобы них добраться, либо нужно включить что-то в инженерном меню чтобы оно начало их писать. Инфы много и вся разная. Пока логов не видел. Если есть какие-то подсказки по этому вопросу - с радостью выслушаю

Comment: > 09-30 02:01:46.230   787  1320 I ActivityManager: Start proc 1625:com.il.GS/u0a88 for activity com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity
> 09-30 02:01:46.297   787  1469 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.il.GS/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity
> 09-30 02:01:46.341   787  1469 W ActivityManager: finishTopRunningActivityLocked , taskNdx is 75, activityNdx is 0
> 09-30 02:01:46.415   787  1496 I ActivityManager: Process com.il.GS (pid 1625) has died

Comment: Ну, на яве когда приложения пишем, то в манифесте можно указать `debuggable="true"` и видеть все логи приложения в logCat AndroidStudio. Подписывание приложения релизным ключом тоже можно атоматизировать и собирать-заливать из студии сразу релизную версию. Так все логи видно

Comment: Попробуйте до этого момента ещё что-то в логах найти. То что вы привели - лишь сообщение о завершении процесса, а нам причину бы) Она, в теории, там должна быть. И выхлоп логов лучше в вопрос добавить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, найду что-то, сразу приаттачу к вопросу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вот такая ерунда там нашлась, спасибо за наводку!

Comment: M2 - это 5 или 6 андроид? А версия студии? Последние поддерживают работу с этими ОС, первые - нет... ну или поддерживают, но могут быть кривости.

Comment: как говорят у нас в фирме "Вы на телефонах а не на мейзу проверяйте" На этом китайце половина функций работает не так на как остальных.

Comment: @kami Meizu M2 это 5.1, у меня такой.

Comment: это только половина ответа на мои вопросы.

Comment: @kami Версия студии: 10.1 Berlin, версия android: 5.1

Comment: @pavel Но ведь все работает так как на остальных. По всем параметрам нормальный андроид-смартфон.  Кроме вот этой ситуации.